# How to conditional regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regex that does one thing if it has 3 instances of `.`in the string, and something else if it has more than 3 instances.

for example

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd // one part of the regex

aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee // the second part of the regex
```

how do I achieve this in either `js` or `c#`?

something like

```
?(\.){4} then THIS else THAT
```

within the regex...

**Update**

Ok basically what I'm doing is this:

I want to switch, for any given `System.Uri`, to another subdomain in an extension method.

The problem I came across is that my domains are usually of the form `http://subdomain.domain.TLD.TLD/more/url`, but sometimes, it can be just `http://domain.TLD.TLD/more/url` (which just points to `www`)

So this is what I came up with:

```
public static class UriExtensions
{
    private const string TopLevelDomainRegex = @"(\.[^\.]{2,3}|\.[^\.]{2,3}\.[^\.]{2,3})$";
    private const string UnspecifiedSubdomainRegex = @"^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/)(()([^:\/\s]+))(:([^\/]*))?((?:\/)?|(?:\/)(((\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?))?$";
    private const string SpecifiedSubdomainRegex = @"^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/)(([^.:\/\s]*)[\.]([^:\/\s]+))(:([^\/]*))?((?:\/)?|(?:\/)(((\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?))?$";

    public static string AbsolutePathToSubdomain(this Uri uri, string subdomain)
    {
        subdomain = subdomain == "www" ? string.Empty : string.Concat(subdomain, ".");

        var replacement = "$1{0}$5$6".FormatWith(subdomain);

        var spec = Regex.Replace(uri.Authority, TopLevelDomainRegex, string.Empty).Distinct().Count(c => c == '.') != 0;
        return Regex.Replace(uri.AbsoluteUri, spec ? SpecifiedSubdomainRegex : UnspecifiedSubdomainRegex, replacement);
    }
}
```

Basically with this code I take the `System.Uri` and:

1. Take just the `subdomain.domain.TLD.TLD` using the `Authority` property.
2. Match it against "pseudo TLDs" (I'm never going to have a registered domain with 2-3 letters that would break the regex, which basically checks for anything ending in `.XX[X]` or `.XX[X].XX[X]`)
3. I strip the TLDs, and end up with either `domain` or `subdomain.domain`
4. If the resulting data has zero dots, I use the `UnspecifiedSubdomainRegex`, because I couldn't figure out how to use `SpecifiedSubdomainRegex` to tell it that if it has no dots on that part, it should return `string.Empty`

My question then is if there is a way to merge these three regexes into something simpler

PD: Forget about javascript, I was just using it to test the regex on the fly

Comment: Note: in the absolute majority of cases, people who ask for a conditional regex don't really need it. Usually it can be avoided by using simpler constructs, like alternation and optional groups. Of course, you'll have to provide more details, namely: "does", "one thing", "something else", "THIS else THAT", and expected output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this using the `(?(?=condition)then|else)` construct. However, this is not available in JavaScript (but it is available in .NET, Perl and PCRE):

```
^(?(?=(?:[^.]*\.){3}[^.]*$)aaa|eee)
```

for example, will check if a string contains exactly three dots, and if it does, it tries to match `aaa` at the start of the string; otherwise it tries to match `eee`. So it will match the first three letters of

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
eee.ddd.ccc.bbb.aaa
eee
```

but fail on

```
aaa.bbb.ccc
eee.ddd.ccc.bbb
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
(?           # Conditional: If the following lookahead succeeds:
 (?=         #   Positive lookahead - can we match...
  (?:        #     the following group, consisting of
   [^.]*\.   #     0+ non-dots and 1 dot
  ){3}       #     3 times
  [^.]*      #     followed only by non-dots...
  $          #     until end-of-string?
 )           #   End of lookahead
 aaa         # Then try to match aaa
|            # else...
 eee         # try to match eee
)            # End of conditional
```

Comment: Omg, I misread his question. I though he need to perform different actions based on regex. +1 to you.

Comment: Emulation of conditionals in Javascript: `(?:(?=condition)aaa|(?!condition)eee)`

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Although this only works for simple cases, it's absolutely fantastic! Thank you so much!
I'm now using it in Oniguruma-flavor RE.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot `condition` here [**must** be of fixed length](https://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, Tim - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:[^.]*\.[^.]*){3}$
```

the regex above will match the string that has exactly 3 dots --- http://rubular.com/r/Tsaemvz1Yi.

```
^(?:[^.]*\.[^.]*){4,}$
```

and this one - for the string that has 4 dots or more --- http://rubular.com/r/IJDeQWVhEB

Comment: and how do I use this in a condition? I want to "if this regex matches, then use this regex, else use this other regex"

Comment: @Nico: using javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp using C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx

Comment: @Nico: regular expression itself is just a string literal. It cannot do anything without using of special functions or operators, like "Hello world" string cannot do anything until you print it, for example.

Comment: I know, but I read something about `?()` and `?=` conditions and it seemed like this kind of thing could be done in regular expressions

Comment: @Nico: there are such constructions, but they don't work like you think they should. They just specify additional conditions the string should meet to be matched by regular expression. And this has nothing to do with programming language control structures.

Comment: @zerkms: Uh, that's exactly what conditional regexes are for. They don't exist in JavaScript, though.

Answer (score 1):

In Python (excuse me; but regexes are without language frontier)

```
import re

regx = re.compile('^([^.]*?\.){3}[^.]*?\.')

for ss in ("aaa.bbb.ccc",
           "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd",
           'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee',
           'a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i...'):
  if regx.search(ss):
    print ss + '     has at least 4 dots in it'
  else:
    print ss + '     has a maximum of 3 dots in it'
```

result

```
aaa.bbb.ccc     has a maximum of 3 dots in it
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd     has a maximum of 3 dots in it
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee     has at least 4 dots in it
a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i...     has at least 4 dots in it
```

This regex' pattern doesn't require that the entire string be analysed (no symbol $ in it). It's better on long strings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for this (as for many other common tasks).

```
public static string AbsolutePathToSubdomain(this Uri uri, string subdomain)
{
    // Pre-process the new subdomain
    if (subdomain == null || subdomain.Equals("www", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        subdomain = string.Empty;

    // Count number of TLDs (assume at least one)
    List<string> parts = uri.Host.Split('.').ToList();
    int tldCount = 1;
    if (parts.Count >= 2 && parts[parts.Count - 2].Length <= 3)
    {
        tldCount++;
    }

    // Drop all subdomains
    if (parts.Count - tldCount > 1)
        parts.RemoveRange(0, parts.Count - tldCount - 1);

    // Add new subdomain, if applicable
    if (subdomain != string.Empty)
        parts.Insert(0, subdomain);

    // Construct the new URI
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
    builder.Host = string.Join(".", parts.ToArray());
    builder.Path = "/";
    builder.Query = "";
    builder.Fragment = "";

    return builder.Uri.ToString();
}
```