# How to upgrade .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0 automatically, including references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm going to upgrade my solution from .net3.5 to .net4.0. But my solution have 120 projects.

I get a macro from here: [Change the Target Framework for all my projects in a Visual Studio Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956415/change-the-target-framework-for-all-my-projects-in-a-visual-studio-2010-solution)

It works, but it only changes the target framework, not the references. i need to remove some references and re-add them for version 4.0.

Is there any method to do this automatically?I dont want to do this for all 120 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try search and replace in all the *.*proj files using a powerful text editor (e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)). It may require [regular expressions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I wrote a perl script to do this.