# .Net Project Target framework Upgrade programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

We have more than 100 projects (in 1.1, 2.0 .net framework) which needs to be upgraded to 4.0/4.5 .net framework.

When we change the target framework of any project from 2.0 to 4.0, then the visual studio upgrades the .*proj and .config file. But no changes are made to any code file.

I want to create a re-usable utility which can be used to scan the source code files for a set of pre-defined features (ex, some old controls, obsolete classes etc); and then update the code files with its compatible feature/version in newer .net framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is to search Google for existing implementations. This site isn't a code generation engine. This is far too big to be easily answerable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the Target Framework for all my projects in a Visual Studio Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956415/change-the-target-framework-for-all-my-projects-in-a-visual-studio-solution)